# Use flag `--experimental-worker` with babel-node

Tags: node.js, babeljs

```
babel-node --experimental-worker app.js
```

Using this command for starting my project in development mode. Output is:

> error: unknown option--experimental-worker'

**config .babelrc:**

```
{ "presets": [ ["env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }], "stage-0", "flow" ], "plugins": [ "transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-flow-strip-types" ] }
```

This flag is needed to use worker threads. Using babel 6.26

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this today and replied to the issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8726#issuecomment-447689197). I've pasted my fix below:

> I was using [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io), and it turns out that there's an option to
>   include environment variables as `NODE_OPTIONS` in the `nodemon.json`
>   file. This did the trick for me:
>
> ```
> {
>   "watch": ["server"],
>   "ext": "js",
>   "env": {
>     "NODE_OPTIONS": "--experimental-worker"
>   },
>   "exec": "babel-node server/server.js"
> }
> ```
>
> How to integrate Nodemon + `worker_threads` into a normal NodeJS app:
>
> 1. Set up [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io)
> 2. Add a `nodemon.json` file to the root folder (example [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md))
> 3. Add this to `nodemon.json`:
>
>    "env": {
>        "NODE_OPTIONS": "--experimental-worker"
>      }
>
> If you're setting up Nodemon for the first time, I found
>   [this](https://alligator.io/workflow/nodemon/) tutorial very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to split your command into two phases:

Phase 1:

```
babel app.js --out-file app-compiled.js
```

And phase 2:

```
node --experimental-worker app-compiled.js
```

In `npm` scripts you can then combine the two:

```
"scripts": {
  "pre-build": "babel ./app.js --out-file ./app-compiled.js",
  "serve": "yarn pre-build && node --experimental-worker ./app-compiled.js"    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It not actually for me already. I am refused to use nodemon and run my code with command

`node --experimental-worker -r babel-register $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION app.js`

It`s help me use exeprimental workers with babel, but with nodemon - not